# Passing data from a dictionary as ViewData

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have defined and initialized a dictionary in my Controller:

```
  Dictionary<string,int> injuryValues = new Dictionary<string,int>();
                int i = 1;
                foreach (var tmpRec in allRecords)
                {
                    if (!injuryValues.ContainsKey(tmpRec.INJURY))
                    {
                        injuryValues.Add(tmpRec.INJURY, ++i);
                    }
                }

                ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] = injuryValues;
```

I want to access this dictionary in my View.  I understand that the ideal way to pass this data is through a ViewModel but for this instance, I need to pass this dictionary in a ViewData container.  How can I do this so that in my View I can access this dictionary?

For example, In my View, use the dictionary along the lines of:

```
 %>

    Dictionary injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string,int>; 

<%
```

What is the correct syntax for me to access this in the View as a View Data container? For my purposes I am  not using a viewmodel though I understand that this is an ideal option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you are defining a dictionary without populating its generic types.

As stated you could use a var, but to help you understand it better you can do something like

```
Dictionary<string,int> injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
```

or

```
var injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
```

Note : made the following test as I saw your comment above stating it was returning errors. Mine however works fine. Here is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var injuryValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        injuryValues.Add("test", 1);
        injuryValues.Add("test2", 2);

        ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] = injuryValues;
        return View();
    }
}
```

and my view

```
    <%
            Dictionary<string, int> injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
            //var injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, int>;

    %>


           <%:injuryList.First().Key%>
           <%:injuryList.First().Value%>
```

Comment: Re:   Dictionary<string,int> injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, int>;  I did try that but I also thought it was incorrect because I wasn't getting the Intellisense or the Red highlighted text within 'ViewData[ ]', so I did not pursue it.  However, in this format VS did not complain about 'string'. I will try this format again, now building some logic with it and see if I can access the dictionary this way.

Comment: If you did your aspx syntax like <% { } %> then that would explain the lack of intellisense. Make sure to have your Dictionary within a <%  %> (no brackets). When you print out the values make sure they are either inside a <%=%> or <%:%> like I have done above.

Comment: Re: your note. I am using MVC 2, so no Razor, just <% %> server side injections into the View. What is the meaning of: @injuryList.First().Key
@injuryList.First().Value?

Comment: @injuryList.First().Key @injuryList.First().Value simply uses LINQ to find the first record of our collection. I added it to prove the records would print correctly. You can remove these lines if not needed.

Comment: Thank you! Removing {} from aspx syntax <% %> worked> Intellisense is on and no complaints.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing "Dictionary" with "var"?

```
var injuryList = ViewData["InjuryDictionary"] as Dictionary<string,int>;
```

Comment: Yes, I have and believed it to be incorrect because I do not get any inelliSense when I scroll over ViewData like with my other ViewData instances on the page  and the string "InjuryDictionary" is not highlighted red also like my other ViewData instances on the page. And VS complains that Element 'string' is not supported in 'Dictionary<string,int>'.

Comment: Perhaps Paul's suggestion to explicitly specify the Dictionary's generic types will better fit your project.

Comment: I just went into detail as to why. Using a var is 100% correct. Behind the scenes a var will be the same as a Dictonary<string,int>

Comment: Indeed .. was just trying to push him onto your answer, as the details and syntax will provide the user more insight/help.